# CSS Selectors, using more than one for the same classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm not 100% sure if I'm saying this right, but basically, right now I am using a global CSS sheet, and in Drupal it generates a CSS sheet for each of my sub-sites based off of this one.

So we use `[class*=""]` to determine which subsite needs which code from this one CSS document.

If I have multiple subsites, that use one chunk of code is there a way to place an or statement?

**For example...**

```
[class*="site-1"] || [class*="site-2"] {
.class {
my css stuff
}}
```

**Not sure if the above works or not.**

```
[class*="site-3"] {
.class2 {
more css stuff
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on any element that has one of the classes:

```
.site1, .site2 {
    ...
}
```

So you can use it for style that is shared between the sites.